# Class Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Source\CollectionFactory does n ot exist

Tags: magento2.3.4

Hi My Problem with Inventory i'm created Folder in app/code/magento/Inventory like that and i'm copy all folders Inventory in this folder i'm right or no and i'm going to make commands
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

but in last command not working i get error

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Class Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Source\CollectionFactory does n
ot exist

and the images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your current approach might not be the most suitable one. Simply copying all inventory folders into the app folder **is not the recommended practice**.

It's essential to override the specific files you need to modify. Consider creating a **Custom Module** and placing the necessary files for overriding in this directory structure: **"app/code/Vendor_name/Module_name/Model/ResourceModel/Source/Collection."**

Comment: i'm fix this but i get new problem to install Inventory and my new problem this  Fatal error: Interface 'Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetProductTypesBySkusInterface' not found in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Magento/InventoryCatalog/Model/ResourceModel/GetProductTypesBySkus.php on line 17